# Horizontal center align a larger item than its container

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a video being played as background for my new home page:

```
<video class="hero" autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="backvid.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="/backvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The video is 1920 x 600, and so for most window sizes it is larger than the viewport it is in.  Centre aligning your average item with margin:0 auto doesn't work here.  I almost want -auto (minus auto) but that doesn't work.

The final desired look is for the video to always be 600px high, though as the window is resized the edges are clipped left and right so that the centre remains in view.  I would like to do this in CSS, and I don't care about pre-HTML 5 browsers.

Comment: Thank you Isherwood - I did look for the question first but missed this.  It is about the same situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I think it will be good. It works with `div`.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Comment: Worked nicely, thank you.  I actually thought I tried this already but clearly something else messed it up which I've since removed.

Comment: note: translating can lead to blurriness due to positioning at half-pixel values.